# gerrit http authentication

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, continuous-integration, gerrit

I'm trying to setup gerrit HTTP authentication.
I am reading the documentation at [gerrit http authentication](http://gerrit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r243/documentation/2.0/config-sso.html) which briefly talks about how to setup apache but where exactly do I put this piece of code and configure apache tomcat?

Otherwise, I researched and found out about "siteminder" for http authentication; am I supposed to be using that instead?

My requirements are that I have my own set of user accounts in my custom system and I need each of my user accounts to be able to interact with gerrit so I figured http would allow custom creation/duplicate of each.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Took me a while to figure this out.

Tomcat was installed and tested.

Then I copied gerrit war file over and put it in tomcat/webapps. Then from the tomcat manager http://[host]:8080/manager/ I installed it (by clicking the start button)

Then I had to install mysql J Connector. Basically download it from Mysql and copy the jar file into tomcat/lib

Next I created a file in tomcat/webapps/gerrit/META-INF called Context.xml

```
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/ReviewDb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
            username="****" password="******" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reviewdb"/>
</Context>
```

Because I had used bouncy castle with the daemon I had to copy the .jar file from original install to tomcat/webapps/gerrit/WEB-INF/lib

Then I managed to start gerrit to see if it was working. Try accessing http://[host]:8080/gerrit This should give you an error from gerrit about bad Apache conf.

Than I reconfigured my apache virtual host like this. So I access gerrit with http://gerrit/gerrit

This then uses http auth before passing your request onto the tomcat server.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin adrian@iceweasel
    ServerName gerrit
    ServerAlias gerrit
    ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" vcommon

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location /gerrit/login/>
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
       AuthUserFile /rddata/www/gerrit/users
       AuthGroupFile /rddata/www/gerrit/groups
       Require group review
       Order Deny,Allow
       Allow from all
    </Location>

    ProxyPass /gerrit/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/gerrit/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian! I will try this out. Usuall with Apache I would know where to put this however with apache tomcat I can't find my http.conf file! Any idea where it is?

Comment: Adrian I'm assuming then your running gerrit through tomcat? Right now I have gerrit ran as a daemon, how do I run it through tomcat to be able to use your method?

Comment: httpd -V should tell you where apache looks for this. I should also update my answer as I bypassed tomcat - I am actually not using it - (I know I tried)

Comment: @user391986 I am going to guess at this - but I think you need to change the ProxyPass to point to the IP/port of the tomcat install - I am trying this out now (since I wanted to use tomcat too) must have got bored trying to figure it out - my tomcat is half installed :-)

Comment: Adrian thanks so much for detailed updates, question I'm trying to follow your steps but everytime I press start in tomcat manager I get "FAIL - Application at context path /gerrit-2.1.8 could not be started"

Comment: Have you looked in tomcat/logs - the 2 mail failures I had where bad database connection and missing bouncy castle

Answer (score 3):

Try this (no tomcat is needed)

- download [gerrit.war](https://gerrit.googlecode.com/files/gerrit-2.6-rc2.war)
- initialize a new project

  ```
  java -jar gerrit.war init -d review
  ```
- set auth method to "HTTP"
- check config files of gerrit and apache

---

etc/gerrit.config

```
[gerrit]
    ...
    canonicalWebUrl = http://hostname:9091/
    ...
[httpd]
    listenUrl = http://*:9090/
    ...
```

vhost config for apache

```
Listen 9091
<VirtualHost *:9091>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyVia Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  <Location /login/>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
    AuthUserFile /path/to/gerrit-users
    Require valid-user
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
  </Location>

  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9090/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I've provided a tutorial on serverfault for setting up Gerrit under tomcat. If you're still interested, here it is:

https://serverfault.com/questions/383573/how-do-i-install-gerrit-under-tomcat-with-ldap